# Os path Join Two args

Tags: python, pandas, join, filepath

i need help to find a file inside a folder by name, i can do this with one file name, how could i do this with two file name?
This is the code used

```
path = r"Z:/Equities/ReferencePrice/"
files = []

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path ,"*OptionOnEquitiesReferencePriceFile*"+"*.txt*")):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = ';')
```

the first file contains the name

"OptionOnEquitiesReferencePriceFile"

the Second file contains the name

"BDRReferencePrice"

how to place the second file how to search between one or the other or both

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that in a straightforward way, so here's an alternative solution (with a function) that you can use :

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

# folder path :
# here in this path i have many files some start with 'other'
# some with 'test and some with random names. 
# in the example im fetchinf only the 'test' and 'other' patterns
dir_path = './test_dir'

def find_by_patterns(patterns, path):
    results = []
    # check for any matches and save them in the results list
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if max([fnmatch(name, pattern) for pattern in patterns]):
                results.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return results

# printing the results
print(find_by_patterns(['test*.txt', 'other*.txt'], dir_path))
```

output:

```
['./test_dir/other1.txt', './test_dir/other2.txt', './test_dir/test1.txt', './test_dir/test2.txt', './test_dir/test3.txt']
```